# aggregate by time php

Tags: php, arrays, time

i have to get an plain array an create a multidimensional array by group the by time interval.

the original array is like this:

```
$one = {
  0 => [
    'nome' => 'ALO/MANO'
    'origem' => 'GRU'
    'voo' => '4730'
    'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
    'hora' => '18:15'
   ],
  1 => [
   'nome' => 'JOHN/DOE'
   'origem' => 'GRU'
   'voo' => '4730'
   'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
   'hora' => '18:15'
  ], 
  2 => [
   'nome' => 'EVA/DOE'
   'origem' => 'GRU'
   'voo' => '4730'
   'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
   'hora' => '18:15'
  ], 
  3 => [
   'nome' => 'CARL/DOE'
   'origem' => 'GRU'
   'voo' => '4730'
   'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
   'hora' => '20:35'
  ], 
  4 => [
   'nome' => 'CARL/DOE'
   'origem' => 'GRU'
   'voo' => '4730'
   'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
   'hora' => '20:55'
  ], 
  5 => [
   'nome' => 'CARL/DOE'
   'origem' => 'GRU'
   'voo' => '4730'
   'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
   'hora' => '22:35'
  ], 
  46 => [
   'nome' => 'CARL/DOE'
   'origem' => 'GRU'
   'voo' => '4730'
   'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
   'hora' => '22:55'
  ], 
 };
```

and i have to make it like this by creating a function to group by hora key like: $result = groupByTime($one, 50);

```
$result = {
 0 => [
   0 => [
    'nome' => 'ALO/RAFAEL'
    'origem' => 'GRU'
    'voo' => '4730'
    'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
    'hora' => '18:15'
  ],
  1 => [
   'nome' => 'JOHN/DOE'
   'origem' => 'GRU'
   'voo' => '4730'
   'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
   'hora' => '18:15'
  ], 
  2 => [
   'nome' => 'EVA/DOE'
   'origem' => 'GRU'
   'voo' => '4730'
   'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
   'hora' => '18:15'
  ] 
], 
1 => [
 0 => [
  'nome' => 'CARL/DOE'
  'origem' => 'GRU'
  'voo' => '4730'
  'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
  'hora' => '20:35'
 ], 
 1 => [
  'nome' => 'CARL/DOE'
  'origem' => 'GRU'
  'voo' => '4730'
  'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
  'hora' => '20:55'
 ], 
 2 => [
  'nome' => 'CARL/DOE'
  'origem' => 'GRU'
  'voo' => '4730'
  'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
  'hora' => '22:35'
 ] 
], 
0 => [
 0 => [
  'nome' => 'CARL/DOE'
  'origem' => 'GRU'
  'voo' => '4730'
  'inicio' => '2018/03/10'
  'hora' => '22:55'
 ]
],  
};
```

i`ve been trying to do for a few days but it seems i got stucked!

Comment: where are your trials?

Comment: sorry i didint get it

Comment: you said __i`ve been trying to do for a few days but it seems i got stucked!__ where are the codes

Comment: private function getInterValMinutes($from, $to) 
 {
  $to_time = strtotime($from);
  $from_time = strtotime($to);
  return round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);
 }



    private function groupByTimeInterval($data, $interval)
    { 
  
  $result = [];
  $length = count($data);
  $a=0;
  for($i = 0; $i < $length ; ++$i) {
   $current = current($data);
   $next = next($data);
   $timeDiff = $this->getInterValMinutes($current['hora'], $next['hora']);
   if($timeDiff <= $interval) {
   
   }
   $a++;
  }
  
  print_r($result); die;


        return $result;
    }

Comment: I put it bellow

Comment: Paste whatever the mess in your comment is to your actual question, it'll be more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for

```
/**
 * Group Elements Of One Array By Hora
 * @param array $arr
 * @return array 
 */
function groupByTimeInterval( $arr )
{
    $indexs = [];
    $new_arr = [];
    foreach ( $arr as $value ) {
        !isset( $indexs[$value['hora']] ) && $indexs[$value['hora']] = count($new_arr);
        $new_arr[$indexs[$value['hora']]][] = $value;
    }
    return $new_arr;
}
```

I tested it using the given array and I've got the following result:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [nome] => ALO/MANO
                [origem] => GRU
                [voo] => 4730
                [inicio] => 2018/03/10
                [hora] => 18:15
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [nome] => JOHN/DOE
                [origem] => GRU
                [voo] => 4730
                [inicio] => 2018/03/10
                [hora] => 18:15
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [nome] => EVA/DOE
                [origem] => GRU
                [voo] => 4730
                [inicio] => 2018/03/10
                [hora] => 18:15
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [nome] => CARL/DOE
                [origem] => GRU
                [voo] => 4730
                [inicio] => 2018/03/10
                [hora] => 20:35
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [nome] => CARL/DOE
                [origem] => GRU
                [voo] => 4730
                [inicio] => 2018/03/10
                [hora] => 20:55
            )

 ...
```

**EDIT**

```
/**
 * Group Elements Of One Array By Hora
 * @param array $arr
 * @param integer $inter
 * @return array 
 */
function groupByTimeInterval( $arr, $inter = 50 )
{
    $indexs = [];
    $new_arr = [];
    foreach ( $arr as $row ) {
        $new_arr[getIndex($indexs,$row,$inter)][] = $row;
    }
    return $new_arr;
}

/**
 * 
 */
function getIndex( &$indexs, $row, $inter )
{
    //print_r( $indexs );
    $date_time = $row['inicio'] . ' ' . $row['hora'];
    foreach ($indexs as $index => $_date_times ){
        foreach ($_date_times as $_date_time) {
            if( $date_time == $_date_time ) return $index;
            if( horaComp( $date_time, $_date_time, $inter ) ){
                $indexs[$index][] = $date_time;
                return $index;
            }
        }
    }
    return ( array_push( $indexs , array($date_time) ) - 1 );
}

/**
 * Compare two given dates and see if the difference is less or equal 50 minutes, if so return true else false.
 * @param string $data_1 YYYY/MM/DD HH:II
 * @param string $data_2 YYYY/MM/DD HH:II
 * @param integer $inter Interval in minutes
 * @return boolean
 */
function horaComp( $date_1, $date_2, $inter )
{
    $date_1_s = strtotime( $date_1 );
    $date_2_s = strtotime( $date_2 );
    return (bool)( abs($date_1_s-$date_2_s)<=$inter*60 );
}
```

Comment: tks for the answer but is almost this, i have to check if hora of the current element is in an given interval (50 minutes) with the next element.
so if hora of the second array is 20:35 and the hora of the thirdy element is 20:55, they're have to be groupped because the difference of hora is less or equal 50 minutes

Comment: You can't do that, as for example if we have those dates: `20:00`, `20:45` and `21:20`, how should we group them! `21:20-20:45 = 35min` and `21:20-20:00 = 1h 20min`, should we group them on the same group.

Comment: IT WORK`S PERFECT! i OWN YOU A BEER!

Comment: It seems not work with longer arrays, by will try to figure out.

Comment: Can I know what's wrong with long arrays? What error/results you get.

Comment: in long arrays not grouping by hora, it seems just groupping on the first element of the array.

you can see [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/richardfeliciano/081f1b81683b6450f763d911c0464221/raw/45bb1ba170477b1d7e823e0609c0120f290a2792/gistfile1.txt)